# How to cast different values to an alphabet

Tags: python, tesseract

I'm a noob student working on a computer vision project.
I'm using google trans library to translate characters extracted with teseract ocr. The extracted text is in Sinhala Language, and I need to transform them into English without translating the meaning. But when using googletrans it translates the meanings as well. I only need the letters to be translated. So I want to create a mapping file with characters in Sinhala language with corresponding values in English. I can't figure out where to start and what is needed to be done. I tried to find online resources but due to my lack of knowledge, I can not connect the dots. Please guide me through this.
Here is a sample of how it should be.

```
(sinhala letter)   (english letters) 
    ට                  = ta
    ක                  =ka
    ර                  =ra
    ම                  =ma
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you should map all the characters using a [dictionary](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp) like so :

```
charcters_map = {
    'ට':'ta',
    'ක':'ka',
    'ර':'ra',
    'ම':'ma'
}
```

then you should loop through you text like so :

```
for letter in text:
    try:
        text = text.replace(letter,characters_map[letter])
    except KeyError: 
        pass # if a letter is not recognized it will just let it as is
```

As pointed out by OneMadGypsy, this overwrites the initial text, this might be a better practice :

```
replaced_text = ''
for letter in text:
    try:
        replaced_text += characters_map[letter]
    except KeyError: 
        replaced_text += letter
```

this replaces all occurences of the current letter with the corresponding value in you dictionary

i hope this helps, and good luck

#### More links :

[replace()](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_replace.asp)

[loop through string](https://buzzcoder.gitbooks.io/codecraft-python/content/string/loop-through-a-string.html)

Comment: good idea. however, in that loop body, the result of the replacement is simply discarded...

Comment: Yes, you're right , my bad, i'm going to fix that :)

Comment: You are shadowing the built-in `map` function, and you are completely overwriting the original string.

Comment: @OneMadGypsy, the built-in map function returns a map object which needs a few more steps to be a string. nevertheless, you re entierly right about overwriting

Comment: @LouisAT ~ What I meant by the `map` part is that you are overwriting the built-in `map` function. In other words, you've eliminated the possibility of ever using `map` again, as it was intended, after your definition.

Answer (score 1):

As @LouisAT stated, a `dict` is the probably the best way to go, but I disagree with the rest of their implementation.

You could create your own `str` type that fully inherits from `str` but adds your phonetics and transliteration properties.

```
class sin_str(str):
    @property
    def __phonetics(self) -> dict:
        return {'ටු':'tu',
                'කා':'kaa',
                'ට':'ta',
                'ක':'ka',
                'ර':'ra',
                'ම':'ma'}
    
    @property
    def transliteration(self) -> str:
        p, t = self.__phonetics, self[:]
        for k,v in p.items(): t = t.replace(k, v)
        return t

#use
text = sin_str('කා')
print(text.transliteration) #kaa
```

Comment: I tried both these methods. they both work for the given characters. but I'm having trouble with a practical implementation of this. 'ටකම' these characters are individual characters in Sinhala. ට = ta , ක =ka. 
In my use case, I've certain letters which derive from these individual characters. for an example, ටු (tu) is derived from ට(ta),  කා (kaa) is derived from ක (ka) and  මි (mi) is from  ම (ma)
these derived letters don't get translated from the dictionary. only the individual characters are translated. What could be the reason for this? additional clarifications can be given if needed

Comment: @dhw156 ~ They don't get translated because they are mulit-characters, and both of our solutions translate single characters at a time. You'll have to do this completely different.

Comment: @dhw156 - I adjusted my answer to work for what you need. Make sure that you put the longest characters FIRST in the dictionary.